Creating a Regression Table with gtsummary for fixest Model: Indicating Inclusion of Fixed Effects and Clustering
I want to use the gtsummary package to create a regression table of a fixest model. I want an indicator in the table showing that the fixed effect is included (for which variable) and any clustering. How can I include this? For example, a checkmark or similar.
